# Cross account Athena DB access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is it possible to access Athena from another account in AWS?

For example:
Athena set up in Account A

lambda set up in Account B

can the lambda or any service in Account B obtain access to Athena in Account A via jdbc connection?

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:athena:default", properties))
```

I cant see how this would be possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access Athena from cross account.  To answer you second question, you can use a JDBC connection to connect Athena to business intelligence tools and other applications, such as SQL workbench. To do this, download, install, and configure the Athena JDBC driver. Also, can you explain your use-case further?

Comment: @ShubhamJoshi So we have an Athena account set up that has data available for us. We want to query that data from a service in another account. I didnt think it was possible to do that without creating a glue catalog or having another athena account connect to the glue catalog. But your saying its possible to connect from one account to another... how will it know which Athena im accessing? Do i need to assume a role?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to have the Lambda function in Account-B use Athena in Account-B, but have the data in Amazon S3 in Account-A. This would not display the existing tables defined in AWS Glue/Amazon Athena from Account-A, but you could access the data stored in S3 in Account-A. This would require the Lambda function to have access permissions to the data in S3 in Account-A. It all depends on whether you want to use the tables already defined in Athena in Account-A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable an AWS Lambda function in Account-A to use Amazon Athena in Account-B, you should:

- Create an **IAM Role** in Account-B and:

  - Grant it permission to use **Amazon Athena**
  - Grant it permission to use **Amazon S3** (since Athena requires the user submitting the query to have access to the data in S3)
  - Modify the **Trust policy** to permit `AssumeRole` from the **IAM Role used by the AWS Lambda function** in Account-A
- Add code to your **AWS Lambda function** that calls `AssumeRole()` to assume the above IAM Role, then use the returned credentials to access Amazon Athena in Account-B

See also: [Cross-account access in Athena to Amazon S3 buckets - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html)

Comment: So in this case by assuming a role for Athena in Account B. When the application uses the JDBC connection. It will use the athena in Account B as the role is associated with that account. correct?

Comment: Yes. When your function calls `AssumeRole()` it will be returned a new set of credentials (Access Key, Secret Key, Session Token) that are valid in Account-B. You should use these credentials to make the connection to Amazon Athena via JDBC (or you can even use an AWS SDK to make the requests via API calls instead of JDBC).